# Using the .RData file

Tags: r

I realize that I overwrote an .R file that took me some time to create. Is it possible to see in my .RData the commands that I ran? I always saved my files as external scripts and have never used the .RData file before so I don't really know what to do and am afraid of loosing it forever.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you have a file in your directory named ".Rhistory"? This file might be hidden on Linux systems.

Read up the help page ?history

Comment: Yes - it's there; thanks for the tip. I just tried loading it, and `history(max.show = Inf)` but it does not go back far enough as it's one day too short.

Answer (score 10):

This is not really a direct answer to your question, but some advice from *The Pragmatic Programmer* that has served me well time and time again to avoid situations like this:

> Always Use Source Code Control

If a process was worth the time it took to record the steps in a `.R` file, then it should be protected by a source code control system.  This gives you many important benefits, two of which are:

- You can recover or rewind your files which provides protection against accidental deletion or modifications that, an hour later, start to seem like they were not such a good idea after all.
- Your work is backed up in one or more locations. Preferably on different computers.

If you have never used source code control before, here are some resources to get you started:

- [Git](http://www.git-scm.org) is a great system that has the benefit of being distributed which makes your files very hard to loose. [gitref.org](http://www.gitref.org) is a greate place to learn about Git and [GitHub](http://www.github.com) provides great hosting for off-site Git repositories.
- [Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/) is another good distributed system. Joel Spolsky, one of the cofounders of this very site, wrote an excellent guide at [hginit.com](http://www.hginit.com).  [Bitbucket](http://www.bitbucket.org) is a great place to host off-site Mercurial repositories---they even allow unlimited private repositories if you need to control access to your work.

Learning source code control was without a doubt the most valuable investment I have ever made in a programming tool. It pays its self back the first time a situation like this comes up.

Comment: I do appreciate the advice. I've dabbled with github a few times, but never quite got the hang of it. I need to start using it; particularly as this was an intricate .R file that I'm not certain I can recreate.

Comment: Working with Notepad++ (and NppToR) you could use "backup copy" of your files created after every file-save. Windows-only solution.

Comment: Even if you're just using mercurial locally, it can be a huge lifesaver and that tutorial is great. A very approachable alternative/first step could be dropbox.com, which works a bit like version control -- it lets you roll back at least five versions and solves the offsite backup problem.

Comment: I didn't have any experience with Mac, but I reckon there are tilde-ending files, since it's UNIX.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using GNU/Linux distro, there's a great chance that you already have backups in your working directory. All you have to do is to use:

- in bash shell:

  `ls -a | grep ~$`
- in R:

  `dir(all.files = TRUE, pattern = "~$")`

Note that `-a` and `all.files = TRUE` are needed only if you want to search hidden files (beginning with `.`), otherwise you can easily omit it.

But you should definitely use Git or SVN or other VCS, as Sharpie already suggested. I would recommend Git (mostly because of GitHub). Though that's only useful if you're hosting an open-source project, otherwise you'll have to pay for GitHub services (and I assume you'd like to skip that one, right?)

Comment: I'm using a Mac with OSX - is it true for this too?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the .RData is the same result you would get if you run `save.image()` - it saves everything that you see when you type `ls()` You can restore this by dragging it into your R Console, or by running the command `load(".RData")`